# What mountain is this white pointed one in my gmail background image?

Tags: mountain-identification

I believe, many of us may have set this theme of mountains on gmail.

Did anybody care to know what mountain is it?

[image]

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14751/what-mountain-is-used-in-the-macos-sierra-desktop-background/14752#14752

Comment: Related https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14749/what-is-this-mountain-seen-from-above-the-banks-lake-region-of-washington-state/14750#14750

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the Himalayan peak, [Ama Dablam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ama_Dablam)

All the theme images are provided by iStockPhoto, this one appears to be cropped from [this image](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-15301941-snow-mountain-summit-pinnacles-dramatic-high-altitude-ridges-himalayas-nepal.php)