# What mountain is used in the MacOS Sierra desktop background?

Tags: california, mountain-identification

I have been curious as to which mountain is in this picture.

[image]

I have tried a reverse Google image search but all I have found is pictures of computers. Presumably it is somewhere in the [Sierra Nevada Mountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierra_Nevada_(U.S.)).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The picture for the Mac OS X Sierra desktop background is of [Lone Pine Peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lone_Pine_Peak). You can find a [similar picture taken by Don Smith at their blog](http://www.donsmithblog.com/2011/11/26/exploring-visual-concepts-texture-and-patterns/), where they mentioned the following:

> In the scene below, I awaited the first light of sunrise to paint the ridges of Lone Pine Peak located in the Alabama Hills just west of Lone Pine, California. The pattern of these ridge lines were there, they were just made evident by the play of alpenglow light and shadow.
>
> -- Don Smith, [Exploring Visual Concepts – Texture and Patterns](http://www.donsmithblog.com/2011/11/26/exploring-visual-concepts-texture-and-patterns/)